Apachi Sedona NoClassDefFoundError: scala/collection/IterableOnce
I am trying to run this code:
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("SedonaTest") \
    .config("spark.jars.packages", "org.apache.sedona:sedona-spark-3.4_2.12:1.6.1,org.datasyslab:geotools-wrapper:1.6.1-28.2") \
    .getOrCreate()

sedona = SedonaContext.create(spark)

But code failed at sedona = SedonaContext.create(spark), I get this error:

 Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o112.sql.: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/collection/IterableOnce


I checked the JAVA_HOME, SPARK_HOME paths; spark-env.sh , .bashrc files and I checked also versions of Scala,Java Spark and Sedona. There is no conflict.
